# Creating a user defined function in oracle SQL called lastnamefirst

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle SQL developper.

I am trying to create a function that will accept two parameters (first and last name) and return them as one variable, with the last name showing up first. Here is my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST
(
varFirstName IN VARCHAR2,
varLastName IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE varFullName VARCHAR2;

DEFINE varFullName := CONCAT(varLastName,' ' ,varFirstName);

  RETURN varFullName;
END LASTNAMEFIRST;
```

I am receiving an error on the semicolon at 'end lastnamefirst' "syntax error"
I keep trying to change small things and that same error just shows up in different places whenever I change things.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. Should be

```
SQL> create or replace function lastnamefirst
  2    (varfirstname in varchar2,
  3     varlastname in varchar2)
  4  return varchar2
  5  as
  6  begin
  7    return varlastname||' '||varfirstname;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select lastnamefirst('Little', 'Foot') result from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------
Foot Little

SQL>
```

What's wrong with your code?

- you don't `DECLARE` within the body; if you do, there's no `DECLARE` keyword at all, and datatype requires length (such as `VARCHAR2(30)`)
- `CONCAT` accepts only two arguments; use a concatenation operator, double pipe `||` instead
- there's no `DEFINE` in PL/SQL

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the Oracle syntax to look more like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST (
   in_FirstName IN VARCHAR2,
   in_LastName IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    v_FullName varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_FullName := in_LastName || ' ' || in_FirstName;

    RETURN v_FullName;
END;  --  LASTNAMEFIRST;
```

This can of course be simplified (say by not using a local variable), but it follows the logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DECLARE` where you have is essentially starting a new code block, which is leading to the error you see. In your code, the `DECLARE`isn't necessary if you move the variable declaration prior to the `BEGIN`. `DEFINE` is also invalid. Something like this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST
(
varFirstName IN VARCHAR2,
varLastName IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
   varFullName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  varFullName := varLastName || ' ' || varFirstName;
  RETURN varFullName;
END LASTNAMEFIRST;
```

This could be simplified further by removing the variable declaration completely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST
(
varFirstName IN VARCHAR2,
varLastName IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN varLastName || ' ' || varFirstName;
END LASTNAMEFIRST;
```